# How can I translate "notable user" into Chinese?

Tags: translation

I have searched for the word **notable**. It means:

- worthy of notice 值得提起
- widely known and esteemed 被广泛所知或者受人尊敬的

and **notable user** in my context may be the second choice. But how can I translate it into a readable or short phrase.

I was trying the **著名用户**, but it is a little bit strange. Is there a better way to translate this phrase.

Add more context:

```
### Notable users

- [GitLab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/)
- [Vim Markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/)
```

Comment: try 显著的 (see iciba for examples)

Comment: it'd be better if you can provide more detailed context

Comment: 著名用户/知名用户 is fine.

Comment: What your context? Take a sentence for example pls.

Comment: dictionaries classify 显, 著 first as adjectives ("notable") (secondly as verbs, 著 also functions as noun  "work ； writings ； book" ), whereas 名 is classified as noun,verb,adjective in that order, therefore some  might think 显著 resembles the English word more closely than 著名，on the other hand it seems 著名，显著 are both 并列复合词，in which case 显,著,名 all function as adjectives。

Comment: @user6065 the problem is native speakers rarely use 显著的 to describe a person. 显著的用户 or 显著用户 sounds very strange.

Comment: @Stan  as confirmed by the many examples for 显著 on iciba

Comment: @Stan 知名用户 seems readable. According to the context these users are all famous.

Comment: @WeiboLi context has added.

Comment: @einverne I couldn't find where "notable users" is used in the links. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @NS.X. I think he's saying whatever thing he is involved in has as notable users: Gitlab and Vim Markdown

Comment: @user6065 which example? Maybe I should emphasize I meant the Chinese translation 显著用户 is strange, but not the English version.

Comment: @Stan there is no disagreement, the examples (10) in iciba for 显著 confirm that native speakers rarely (if ever) use 显著 for persons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that 知名用户 sounds natural, but I don't know in what context it is used, and what it really refers to.

Answer (score 0):

notable user: widely known user   知名用户、名人用户

notable user：esteemed user    尊贵用户

hope this could be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

From the given context, It seems you are referring to a list of users who are using your project on GitHub, and you only want to mention a few of the "well known" users

In this context, I would use

`知名用户` or  `知名使用者`